# OSX Parsing Error HexNumber format

Tags: c#, macos, parsing, unity-game-engine, hex

I am currently having a weird issue while trying to parse a hex string in c#, on a osx machine.

Here's the line that's causing me trouble :

```
string userID = SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier;
userID = Int64.Parse(userID, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber).ToString();
```

The initial string is something like this : XXX999X-XX99-9

The error I'm getting is as follows :

```
FormatException: Input string was not in the correct format: Did not parse entire string. pos = 8 s.Length = 15
```

Now clearly the "-" is what is causing the problem here. Is there a way to avoid this ? How can I parse my hex hash correctly ? I'm doing this to generate unique user IDs, so I don't know if I can simply replace symbols that aren't allowed or something. This issue only appears to be a problem on OSX devices.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the "-"?

```
string userID = SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier.Replace("-", string.Empty);
userID = Int64.Parse(userID, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber).ToString();
```